# How can i store image in my project hosted in openshift?

Tags: jsp, openshift, jfreechart

i am trying to create chart and save chart in image folder. it works fine locally but when i hosted it in openshift online it doesn't work.

```
String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
   File savedFile = new File(root+"\\images\\piechart.jpg");
   ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(savedFile, piechart, 700, 400);
```

root gives null so saving is not working ... please help to store image.

Comment: Can you `writeChartAsJPEG()` instead?

Comment: Thanks ..... it works fine now after making this change i.e writeChartAsJPEG() with java servlet... :) happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving the chart as an image in a local folder, you can use one of the variations of [`ChartUtilities.writeChartAs…`](http://ChartUtilities.writeChartAs) to write the image to the servlet's `OutputStream`.

```
ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(response.getOutputStream(), …);
ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(response.getOutputStream(), …);
```