# jFreeChart in Java servlet doesn't work

Tags: java, servlets, charts, jfreechart

I don't get why my servlet is not generating the line chart.

```
DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
dataset.setValue(new Double(10050.5), "Sechsmonatsumsatz", "März");
dataset.setValue(new Double(12989.98), "Sechsmonatsumsatz", "April");

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Gesamtumsätze der letzten sechs Monate",
            null ,"Umsatz in €" , dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);

ServletUtilities.setTempFilePrefix("gesamtmonatsumsatz");
String filename = ServletUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(chart, 500, 300, request.getSession());
String url = request.getContextPath() + "/servlet/Statistik?filename=" + filename;

out.println("<IMG SRC='" + url + "' width='500' height='300' "
    + "border='0' usemap='#" + filename + "'>");
```

This is in my "Statistik" servlet  and this here is my web.xml entry:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Statistik</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.Statistik</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Statistik</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Statistik</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The values don't have any meaning yet, it's just a test. When I go to the website now, it says that the picture is broken because it couldnt load (couldn't be found).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: put a breakpoint in your servlet, most likely you'll see that it is not invoked by browser.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30430770/230513).